# Calculation of derivatives of a function

Tags: calculus, integration, matrices

[image]

I'm trying to understand the usage of w,x here. I have to find the partial derivatives of the function to form a matrix later on. But w,x seem to have odd <> symbols around. Can somebody explain what this part `-<w,x>` means?

Comment: $\langle w, x \rangle= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} w_kx_k$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition

Comment: @MartinR Ty so much of that. Any suggestion on how to use dot product here to find derivative of the above equation?

Comment: What exactly do you want by differentiating the function?